# Angular 14 FormControl two-way binding

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

How come this doesn't work?

I would expect that the name variable that is passed as default value to the `FormControl` would also be updated when the control is.

```
 it('FormControl value changes are reflected in input var', () => {
    let name = 'OldName';
    const control = new FormControl(name);
    control.setValue('NewName');

    expect(name).toBe('NewName'); 
  });
  // OUTPUTS: Expected 'OldName' to be 'NewName'.
```

Comment: Why would you expect the variable "name" to be changed? Are you using two way databinding? From the snippet you posted I would not expect it changes its value.

Comment: Even if ```FormControl``` and it's ```setValue``` were to behave like your expectation, it still wouldn't work. ```name``` is passed by value not by reference.

Comment: Amt - Somehow i was under the impression that it was a reference and not a value that i passed to it. 
LeBavarois - In the scenario where i use this im not two-way binding via ngModel if thats what you refer to.